# Geometric representation of the plane $y+2z = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to wrap my head around the geometric representation of the plane $$y + 2z = 1$$.

I know I can rewrite the equation on this form: 
$$0x + y + 2z - 1 = 0$$
So $x$ can assume any value, but what does this actually mean? How would that plane look?

Comment: @Bye_World Why don't you turn these two comments into an answer?  You could include how to pass from the implicit to parametric representation and back, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is not in the plane equation, then this plane is perpendicular to the coordinate $(y, O, z)$ plane.

Like in two-dimensional case - the equation $y=1$ ($x$ is not in this equation) defines a straight line, perpendicular to the $(O, y)$ axis.

And in general, *any* equation $F(y,z)=0$ defines *cylindrical* surface in three-dimensional space, which is perpendicular to the $(y, O, z)$ plane.

Answer (score 0):

Terminology could be sometimes imprecise and confusing. What one really means by saying "$y + 2z = 1$ represent a plane" is that the *set*
$$
\{(x,y,z)\mid y+2z=1\}\tag{1}
$$
which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be visualized as a plane. The set in (1) can be read as

> the set of all the points $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which *satisfy* the equation 
>   $$
> y+2z=1.
> $$

If you want to know about why (1) is a plane in the Euclidean space, you could read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Point-normal_form_and_general_form_of_the_equation_of_a_plane) Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about this is to draw the **line** y+ 2z= 1 in yz-plane.  When z= 0, y= 1 and when y= 0, z= 1/2 so this is the line through (1, 0) and (0, 1/2)- again that is in the yz-plane.  That line extends to the **plane** parallel to the x-axis.